# What are APP_CLIENT_ID and SERVER_CLIENT_ID and where do I find them?

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm trying to implement server-side API access for my iOS app. The Google docs ([here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access)) mention `APP_CLIENT_ID` and `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` in their code sample in step 2.

Here's their code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"APP_CLIENT_ID";
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = @"SERVER_CLIENT_ID";

  // Additional scopes, if any
  // [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[ @"other_scope" ];

  return YES;
}
```

What are `APP_CLIENT_ID` and `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` and where do I find them? Are they both in the Google Developers Console?

Comment: Look under "APIs & auth" in the Developers Console.  The "Credentials" section will have client ID's  you can paste in place of "`APP_CLIENT_ID`" & "`SERVER_CLIENT_ID`".

Comment: So is the `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` the `client_id` inside the generated JSON key file under the Service account and the `APP_CLIENT_ID` the Client ID listed under Client ID for iOS application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace the `APP_CLIENT_ID` string with an installed application OAuth 2.0  Client ID for the iOS app, configured by adding credentials with the following radio selected:

[image]

The `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` string stores a Web server OAuth 2.0 Client ID and is configured from the console as:

[image]

The server client ID, listed under "Client ID for web application" in the console, is only used if you retrieve an authorization code to authorize your server in hybrid authorization scenarios and is optional. When specifying a `SERVER_CLIENT_ID`, you retrieve an authorization code and can exchange the code for a refresh token on your backend services when you authorize the user from the iOS app.

The client IDs traditionally have been configured via the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developer.google.com) as [described here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_1_creating_the_console_name_project). However, using the latest libraries, you can [generate a configuration](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) and load it as explained in the [iOS developer guide for Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating).

Comment: So in a hybrid authorization scenario (which I am trying to implement the iOS side without help from our web server side) is the `SERVER_CLIENT_ID` the "Client ID" listed under "Client ID for web application"?

Comment: Yes, you got it. By using the `SERVER_CLIENT_ID`, you can exchange the code using the server's settings instead of having to use the iOS app's settings.