# Google Sign in server auth code nil iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

We have Google sign in our application.We are providing serverClientID at the time of request of login.

We are getting user.serverAuthCode as nil.

Our request is like below :

```
func googleLogin(){
            var configureError: NSError?
            GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
            assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

            let gid = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist") {
                let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
                gid?.serverClientID = "our servers cliet id as configured over firebase"

// This client id of our ios app we are getting from
// GoogleService-info.plist 
                gid?.clientID = myDict!.value(forKey: "CLIENT_ID") as! String

            }
            //        gid?.serverClientID = "our_servers" // TODO: fetch from plist
            gid?.scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly")
            print("\nClient Id: \(gid!.clientID!) Server Client Id: \(gid!.serverClientID!)\n")
            gid?.delegate = self

        }
```

We are trying to get the `serverAuthCode` as follows :

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let auth = user.serverAuthCode
            print(auth)
            let fullName = user.profile.name
         } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

But its `serverAuthCode` is null we are not sure what may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 9):

The catch is that the server auth code will only be sent the first time the user logs in. The user must have just seen the confirmation screen. On all subsequent logins, no server auth code will be sent. Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions and removed the credentials for your app, then you'll get a server auth code.

Comment: Still getting nil . This answer helped me though to get a refresh token.

Answer (score 4):

`GIDSignInDelegate ,GIDSignInUIDelegate` use 2 delegates.

```
let signin : GIDSignIn = GIDSignIn .sharedInstance()
signin.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true;
signin.uiDelegate = self
signin.delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently() // this for swift 3.0
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

**Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google**

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
          present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view**

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
          dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**completed sign In**

```
    public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            let imageurl = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 1080)
            print("Gmail id %@" ,userId!)
            print("Gmail token %@" ,idToken!)
            print("Gmail full name %@" ,fullName!)
            print("Gmail first name %@" ,givenName!)
            print("Gmail last name %@" ,familyName!)
            print("Gmail emailid %@" ,email!)

            print("Gmail id %@" ,imageurl!)

        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

**Don't forgot this to add in info.plist file**

```
  <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.************************</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I don't get it how from this answer you can get the authCode.

Answer (score 3):

***Swift / IOS Sign-in with google***

I can solved the same problem using

**googleUser.authentication.idToken**

```
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor googleUser: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return
    }
    // Signed in successfully, forward credentials to MongoDB Realm.
    
    let app = App(id: "application-0-fkaqn")
    let id  = googleUser.authentication.idToken
    let credentials = Credentials.googleId(token: googleUser.authentication.idToken)
    
    app.login(credentials: credentials) { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to log in to MongoDB Realm: \(error)")
            case .success(let user):
                
                print("Successfully logged in to MongoDB Realm using Google OAuth.")
                
                
                // Now logged in, do something with user
                // Remember to dispatch to main if you are doing anything on the UI thread
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `OpenID Connect` option should be enabled and `Client ID` should be the iOS client id and not the Web.

Answer (score 1):

You must set clientId and server clientId in the app delegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = ""

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().serverClientID = ""

You can see the difference in these by reading [CLIENT_ID vs SERVER_CLIENT_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879990/what-are-app-client-id-and-server-client-id-and-where-do-i-find-them/30880417#30880417)

Comment: It worked for me, I will edit the answer to add some extra information that helped me fix it

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to post an updated answer to fix this issue.
I'm using `swift 4.2` and I'm doing the following to obtain the `serverAuthCode`

```
let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration(
    clientID: "YOUR_IOS_CLIENT_ID", 
   serverClientID: "YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID"
)
    
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let user = user else { return }
        
    let code = user.serverAuthCode // Send to server
    print("serverAuthCode: \(code)")
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Google login in my app also.

Here is the solution that worked for me.

Swift 3 :-

```
let serverAuth = user.serverAuthCode

if serverAuth != nil {
   //Server auth is received successfully so you can user navigation.
}
else{
    //Here we make the user logout programatically. So now onwards if user clicks log in with google we won't get nil serAuthCode
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
}
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I tried to logout at the start of my app and then I got nil again!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. In order to get he serverAuthCode do you need to set the serverClientID in your backend.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.serverClientID = "your-server-side-id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Google Identity documentation, the server client ID need to be configured in the Info.plist with the `GIDServerClientID` as the key.

```
<key>GIDServerClientID</key>
<string>YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID</string>
```

Note the server client ID is different from the iOS app client ID. The `GIDSignInResult.serverAuthCode` will be populated after the server client ID is configured.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating