# getServerAuthToken from google_sign_in package returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to retrieve the google server auth code via [google_sign_in package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and worked my way through multiple git hub issues and finally found this [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/2116), which is supposed to fix the issues with this endeavour.

In this pull request, for iOS, it is suggested to add the following lines to `GoogleService-Info.plist`:

```
<key>SERVER_CLIENT_ID</key>
<string>YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID</string>
```

I tried to use the client id for my iOS Flutter App I created via Google Cloud Platform / API & Services / Credentials for my Firebase project, but `getServerAuthCode` still returns null.

Where can I find the correct server client id?

*/edit:* i also tried creating a Client ID for Web application from the google console as described here [What are APP_CLIENT_ID and SERVER_CLIENT_ID and where do I find them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879990/what-are-app-client-id-and-server-client-id-and-where-do-i-find-them) but `getServerAuthCode`still returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google_sign_in package implementation is wrong. I used the fix provided [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57712) and was able to retrieve the server auth token.

> You can just add google_sign_in your project like (in your
> pubspec.yaml file)

```
  google_sign_in:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/aseef17/plugins.git
      path: packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in
      ref: master
```

> And add a dependacy override for google_sign_in_platform_interface

```
dependency_overrides:
  google_sign_in_platform_interface:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/aseef17/plugins.git
      path: packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in_platform_interface
```

> To get this to work in for iOS, you have to add a new key in your
> GoogleService-Info.plist file

```
<key>SERVER_CLIENT_ID</key> <string>YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE</string>
```

Where the server client id can be created in your Firebase project via Google Cloud Platform / API & Services / Credentials. (**use web application for iOS!** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879990/what-are-app-client-id-and-server-client-id-and-where-do-i-find-them))

Comment: This works, but I'm running into dependency version conflicts with google_sign_in_platform_interface, tuple, and quiver. I'm sure I'll figure it out, but this is such a pain as solutions go.